# BackgroundImage con bordes transparentes

Tags: css, reactjs

Me gustaría poder hacer un backgroundImage con los bordes transparentes en React/Nextjs, o al menos algo por el estilo para que la transición de un punto a otro sea más agradable. Hasta ahora he intentado varias cosas con css pero en ningún momento he podido llegar a nada y no se me ocurren más ideas:

```
import { Box, Button, Card, Grid, Link, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react'

import ProfilePic from '@/public/images/avatar.jpg'

export const PresentationLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Grid id='Index' container
            display={'flex'}
            flexDirection={'row'}
            justifyContent={'space-between'}
            alignItems={'center'}
            minHeight={'100vh'}
        >
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} xl={5} >
                <Typography variant='h1' component={'h1'}>XIX</Typography>
                <Typography variant='h2' component={'h2'}>Aarón Quintanal Martín</Typography>

                <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'flex-start'} sx={{
                    marginTop: '2em',
                    marginBottom: '2em'
                }}>
                    <Typography variant='body1'>
                        Soy un desarrollador multiplataforma, especializado en tecnologías como Angular y React,
                        creo soluciones versátiles y eficientes que brindan experiencias coherentes en diversos
                        dispositivos y sistemas operativos. Con un enfoque ágil y conocimientos sólidos, busco
                        superar las limitaciones de plataforma y ofrecer soluciones innovadoras que se adapten
                        a las demandas del mundo digital.
                    </Typography>
                </Box>

                <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'end'}>
                    <NextLink href={'/#Contact'} passHref legacyBehavior>
                        <Link>
                            <Button color='primary' variant='outlined'>Contacto</Button>
                        </Link>
                    </NextLink>
                </Box>
            </Grid>


            {/* ESTO ES EL GRID CON LA IMAGEN */}
            <Grid
                item
                xs={12} md={5} xl={7}
                minHeight={'calc(100vh - 15vh)'}
                sx={{
                    display: { xl: 'flex', md: 'flex', sm: 'none', xs: 'none' },
                    position: 'relative',
                    backgroundImage: `url(${ProfilePic.src})`,
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    backgroundPosition: 'center',
                    backgroundClip: 'content-box',
                }}
            >
            </Grid>

            {/* ESTO ES EL GRID CON LA IMAGEN */}


        </Grid>
    )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como estás?

Espero sea de ayuda, según percibo tu pregunta:

Si necesitas darle un toque mas sutil a esta IMG que tienes, te sugeriría por tratar de desvanecer dicha imagen en sus bordes con un efecto llamado Blur:

ejemplo, te comparto como hacerlo con un DIV:

```
div {
background: #fff;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 400px;
height: 150px;
padding: 50px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 10px #000;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias